# .net framework compatibility

Tags: .net

.Net framework 3.5 has been installed in a PC. In that PC, I like to install the application which developed using .Net 1.1 framework.

Should I install .Net 1.1? If I do that will it cause any problems?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3.5 installs .NET 1.1 also. Hence in general the app will run fine. But Vista onwards you need to separately install a special .NET 1.1 re-distributable.

Comment: You mean from windows 7 onwards, I have to separately install .Net 1.1?

Comment: No not only Windows 7,Vista & Windows 2008 too. Vista has .NET 2 (without .NET 1.1) pre installed.

Comment: Ok, Can I install .Net 1.1 on top of .Net 2 (preinstalled)?

Comment: Yes. There is a special vway to install .NET 1.1 on Vista. 

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/12/27/install-microsoft-net-framework-11-on-windows-vista-fix-regsvcsexe-fails-error/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the frameworks are mostly backward compatible. So try running the app on 3.5.